# How to generate shipping number and print labels for Fedex in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, fedex

I am using Fedex shipping in Magento. I have created a developer account on Fedex developer section and get Account ID, Test Key, Password etc and added these in Magento Admin section for Fedex shipping method.
After this what i need to do? I have searched for documentation but didn't find any documentation for next steps like how to generate shipping tracking number and how to print shipping labels?

Comment: Hey, @Devender Patel, I hope you found some solution to your question , as i am facing same issue .Can yiu suggest if know something.